# Multipeer - Peer Connection Strength detection

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I have been searching around and cannot seem to find anything. I have found information about detecting a wifi hotspot strength but not multipeer.

I am looking to get a value for the connection strength of peers in a multipeer network is this possible in `ios` and `android`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the Multipeer Connectivity Framework, but what you could do is implement your own method of determining a device's signal strength [as in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strenghth-in-ios-reachability), and then pass that signal strength value to peers in your `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`'s `discoveryInfo`