# Show current internet speed in iOS

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am just looking for integrating iOS [widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite&hl=en) which shows current internet speed (for eg. in certain third party app downloading Movie with **1MBPS** so the widget on the iPhone will show speed as **~1MBPS**).

> **In iOS we can determine internet speed by calculating total File size with current downloaded bytes with certain time. But this is not
>   sound elegant.**

Answer Found but not Relevant

- [StackLink1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strength-in-ios-reachability/14584397#14584397)
- [StackLink2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635804/how-to-check-the-network-speed-using-swift)

Can it possible with `URLSession` or *simply as of now No apple API available ?*

Comment: Please refer this answer, if it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/41739233/5241777

Comment: This may help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Comment: @rmaddy, as you mention duplicate, this is not at all answered. My question is clearly diffrent.

Comment: @Akshay did you get any clue on this?