# How to detect WiFi signal(speed of network) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on app to find the signal strength of WiFi Network. Because in Some case we have Wifi Connected but No internet access.
I want achieve how YouTube App in IOS Change the Video Quality based on Network Speed.

Comment: You need to transfer a file of known size from your server and measure how long it takes to get an estimate of network transfer speed.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39954864/7512091
He created a function to download image from server and calculate elapsed time.

Comment: @Premkumar You need to check this link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/1618923-signalstrength

Comment: The signal strength won't tell you much about the actual transfer speed; It is rarely the WiFi signal on its own that determines transfer speed;

Comment: @Ram I am new to this type of networking Concept. I don't get any clear picture about how to use NEHotSpotNetwork. Can please help me.

Comment: @Premkumar Refer those sources - https://medium.com/@prvaghela/nehotspothelper-register-an-app-as-a-hotspot-helper-cf92a6ed7b72 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767138/nehotspothelper-register-not-received-call-back-ios11 - Maybe It will give some ideas to you.