# How to retrieve data from this class?

Tags: swift, networking, speed-test

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887748/right-way-of-determining-internet-speed-in-ios-8) I'm trying to grab speed data from the class, but I cannot figure how.

Let's say I have a class SpeedTest; in `MyViewController` I instantiate:

```
let mySpeedTest = SpeedTest()
```

starting test

```
mySpeedTest.startSpeedTest(usedVC: self)
```

now, how do I grab the result in my `MyViewController`?

Comment: you need to reference this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47727677/5820010

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need

```
mySpeedTest.checkForSpeedTest()

mySpeedTest.speedTestCompletionBlock =  { [weak self] (megabytesPerSecond ,error)  in

    print(megabytesPerSecond)
}
```

Comment: why this message "Variable 'self' was written to, but never read"

Comment: you can remove  `[weak self]` if you won't going to use any self property inside the callback