# Why doesn't path.status report the network connection status correctly in my Swift app?

Tags: swift, networking, nwpathmonitor

I have some swift code which uses the Network framework to detect when network connectivity is available or not. If I have wifi turned on and I run my code my code reports that `path.status` is `.satisfied` and if I then turn off my wifi my code reports that `path.status` is `.satisfied` again. But then if I turn on my wifi again `path.status` is reported as `.unsatisfied` then a second later it reports it as `.satisfied`. What on earth is going on? I would expect `path.status` to change immediately when wifi is turned off and on and off etc.

Here is my NetworkServices class;

```
final class NetworkServices {
    
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()
        
    private let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    
    private let monitor: NWPathMonitor
    
    public private(set) var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    public private(set) var connectionType: ConnectionType = .unknown
    
    enum ConnectionType {
        case wifi
        case cellular
        case wiredEthernet
        case unknown
    }
    
    private init() {
        monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    }
    
    public func startMonitoring() {
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            self?.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            print("DEBUG: path.status = \(path.status); isConnected = \(self!.isConnected)")
            self?.getConnectionType(path)
        }
    }
    
    public func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }
    
    private func getConnectionType(_ path: NWPath) {
        if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
            connectionType = .wifi
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
            connectionType = .cellular
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
            connectionType = .wiredEthernet
        } else {
            connectionType = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

I call the `startMonitoring` method in my AppDelegate file's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: Why would you expect path.status to change immediately when wifi is turned off and on?  Is that assumption correct or not?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/57502517/6576315 ?

Comment: @Shadowrun My understanding is that the closure is called every time there is a change in the network connectivity.

Comment: When it notices a change in connectivity... How does it notice? If you're monitoring using the .background quality of service, will it immediately do anything?

Comment: @Stephen501 what is the setup you are using to test this?

Answer (score 0):

As you turn on wifi, It notify for `NWPath` update but until then connection has not been established, it takes some moment to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The pathUpdateHandler does not work properly in an iOS simulator but works as expected on a real device.