# How to calculate upload speed or average speed of internet in ios

Tags: objective-c, swift, networking, alamofire

I am developing an app where i need to calculate average speed (upload and download) of wifi internet. I have searched on google but most of the links showing calculations to get download speed. for download speed i have found code on [Right way of determining internet speed in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887748/right-way-of-determining-internet-speed-in-ios-8) link . but there is not description to get upload speed or to calculate average speed. Is there any way to calculate it or is there any pod available?