# Test connection speed in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, download, connection, latency

I am currently working on a project which have a part to test my connection speed and retrieve the results.

The results should contains the following:

```
Downlink Data Throughput(Mbps)
Maximum Downlink Data Rate(Mbps)
Avg Downlink Data Rate(Mbps)
Session Duration(mSec)
Latency / Ping Test(mSec)
```

I have found the [speedTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strength-in-ios-reachability) which I can basically use it to get the Max and Avg Data Rate and session duration(the time to download the file)

But how am I supposed to get the Downlink Data throughput and Ping ?
Can anyone help me how to retrieve those data?

Comment: You have to do it yourself.  Create a connection, download some stuff and measure whatever you want.  There's nothing out there that's going to do it for you.

Comment: @Avi i know i should do it by myself, but i am asking how to retrieve the downlink data throughput and ping? what should be the method to accomplish it? the definition of these 2 made it unclear for me to know how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check ping latency,

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDate *start;

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet
{
    self.start=[NSDate date];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet
{
    NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
    double latency = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:self.start]*1000.0;

    //TODO - Do something with latency
}
```

*Edit on 7-April-2017*

You may also want to see this github project: https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing

Comment: Your link is unavailable