# How to detect at realtime the increase/decrease of cellular signal power in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, reachability

My app (it is an app store app) is able to connect via 3G/4G/LTE/Edge etc... however it cannot detect at realtime (via a callback perhaps) that the strength of the signal have been modified. For example: If I am connected with 4G and I am in the "corner" where the signal is EDGE or 2G I would like to disable some functionality. Also I would like to re-enable the functionality with the signal becomes 4G again.

I have seen the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` class and also those values are offered in the SDK

```
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS          __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge          __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA         __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA         __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA         __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x        __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD         __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE           __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
```

but how can the app receive a notification if one of those values are active. I have some code that reads from the CTTelephoneNetworkInfo and the values I am taking back are correct, however this is done when I am calling the methods manually.

Comment: Please state in your question if the app you are working on is for the Apple store or enterprise app. The solution for each could be different.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955390/4557505 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14584397/4557505 , it may help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To detect cellular signal power I use `CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification`.

You can try this code :

```
import CoreTelephony

private var info: CTTelephonyNetworkInfo!

func createObserver() {
    self.info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo();
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "currentAccessTechnologyDidChange",
            name: CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification, object: self.observerObject)
}

func currentAccessTechnologyDidChange() {
    if let currentAccess = self.info.currentRadioAccessTechnology {
        switch currentAccess {
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS:
            print("GPRS")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge:
            print("EDGE")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA:
            print("WCDMA")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA:
            print("HSDPA")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA:
            print("HSUPA")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x:
            print("CDMA1x")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0:
            print("CDMAEVDORev0")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA:
            print("CDMAEVDORevA")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB:
            print("CDMAEVDORevB")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD:
            print("HRPD")
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE:
            print("LTE")
        default:
            print("DEF")
        }
    } else {
        print("Current Access technology is NIL")
    }
}
```

I've tested it on my iphone by turning on/off airplane mode and I've noticed that sometimes I have to wait a bit more time for notification. So maybe the better way in your case will be just called `info.currentRadioAccessTechnology` and get the result when you need it. Of course, remember to remove observer when you don't need it anymore.

Apple documentation about this :

> `currentRadioAccessTechnology`
>   Discussion:
>   The current radio access technology the device is registered with. May be `NULL` if the device is not registered on any network.

Additionaly, I do some research and I found an interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584397/5433235) which might help you.

Simple Obj-C version :

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>


CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *ctInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"current access radio access did change to : %@", ctInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology); 
}];
```