# Notification of iOS mobile connection type changes [e.g. 3G to 4G] in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Is there a way in Swift to get a **notification** every time the cellular connection type **changes** (e.g. from 3G to Edge) without polling the state regularly?

I know how to determine the connection type with the [serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/3024510-servicecurrentradioaccesstechnol) property but failed to wrap it into a KVO or to add an observer.

The [best attempt](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691737) I found was using the NotificationCenter but in my case it did not notify on connection changes.

If anyone could provide an example or give me a hint on how to implement this I would be very thankful.

Comment: Can [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/3024512-servicesubscribercellularprovide) help you ? You define a var in the global subscriber with a function that will be called upon changes.

Comment: According to the documentation this only gets raised if the provider has changed but not on switching connection types.

Comment: I think this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605546/2894790

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect at realtime the increase/decrease of cellular signal power in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481141/how-to-detect-at-realtime-the-increase-decrease-of-cellular-signal-power-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

**This is Objective-C code, you just need to convert it to Swift**

Import Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) and try this,

```
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

//Try this
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];
    
    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    
    if(status == NotReachable)
    {
       NSLog(@"none");
        //No internet
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        NSLog(@"Wifi");
        //WiFi
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN)
    {
        NSLog(@"WWAN");
    
    
    //connection type
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    _carrier = [[netinfo subscriberCellularProvider] carrierName];
    
    if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
        NSLog(@"4G");
    }
    
    }
```

References(Links may broke in future) :

- [iOS Detect 3G or WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938778/3411787)
- [Detect carrier connection type (3G / EDGE / GPRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs)
- [What are the differences between 1G, 2G, 3G, 4G and 5G?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-1G-2G-3G-4G-and-5G)
- [CDMA2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDMA2000)
- [wiki 2G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G)
- [What is the difference between CDMA and WCDMA network sim](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-CDMA-and-WCDMA-network-sim)
- [What is "EV-DO Rev. A"?](http://www.mobileburn.com/definition.jsp?term=1xEV-DO+Rev+A)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, when testing this on the simulator in combination with the Network Link Conditioner I still could not get a notification on network changes. Did you manage to run this successfully?

Also i wonder if there is a more recent solution since CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification is deprecated in iOS 12.