# Continuous network connectivity check in ios

Tags: ios

I am developing an internet based ios app and I need to check for internet continuously and i tried using reachability classes but it does not notify when internet is lost, it is giving notification at the first time when the app launches but and at the time when not connected to any wifi or Lan.I am new to ios and don't know how to do it. I tried all the solutions posted on stack overflow but i could not find the suitable solution.Can you provide me solution which checks the network connection continuously.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strength-in-ios-reachability

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength

Comment: I tried all the solutions posted on stack overflow but i could not find the suitable solution.Can you provide me solution which checks the network connection continuously.