# NSURLSesssionDelegate NSURLSessionDataDelegate functions not triggering with dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I have a class to measure the bandwidth of the network using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584397/3401923).
I tried to rewrite the class in Swift using the same functions:

```
class BandwidthChecker : NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

var startTime = NSDate()
var endTime = NSDate()
var bytesReceived = 0
var completionHandler : ((speed: Double, error: ErrorType?)->Void)?;

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func testDownloadSpeeWithURL(url: NSURL, timeout: NSTimeInterval, completionHandler: (speed: Double, error: ErrorType?)->Void) {
    self.startTime = NSDate()
    self.endTime = self.startTime
    self.bytesReceived = 0
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = timeout
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeout

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url).resume()
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    self.startTime = NSDate()
    self.endTime = self.startTime
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.bytesReceived += data.length
    self.endTime = NSDate()
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    let elapsed = self.endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.startTime)
    let speed = elapsed != 0 ? (Double(self.bytesReceived) / elapsed / 1024.0 / 1024.0 ) : -1

    // timeout is no error, still measure speed
    if error == nil || (error!.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error!.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
        self.completionHandler!(speed: speed, error: nil)
    } else {
        self.completionHandler!(speed: speed, error: error)
    }
}
}
```

I'm testing this code with a unit test (Yes its going to the "real" internet, I will mock it after I know its working):

```
func testBandwidth() {
    let bandwithChecker = BandwidthChecker()
    let asyncExpectation = expectationWithDescription("longRunningFunction")
    var errorResult : ErrorType?
    var speedResult : Double
    speedResult = 0

    bandwithChecker.testDownloadSpeeWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip")!, timeout: 10, completionHandler: {(speed, error) -> Void in
        errorResult = error
        speedResult = speed
        asyncExpectation.fulfill()
    })

    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(20) { error in
        XCTAssertNil(error)
        if errorResult != nil {
            XCTFail("Error while measuring bandwith")
            print("#error:",errorResult)
        } else {
            XCTAssert(speedResult>0)
            print("##### SPEED #####\n")
            print("speed: \(speedResult) MB/s\n")
            print("#################\n")
        }
    }

}
```

This should give me a result after 10 secs, but apparently I get a timeout from  `waitForExpectationWithTimeout` after 20 secs. Breakpoints in `didReceiveData`, `didCompleteWithError` and `didReceiveResponse` are not reached at all.

When I change the url in the test to an invalid url (e.g. `"invalid url"`), the `didCompleteWithError` does in fact trigger and gives me an invalid url error.

I'm helpless at this point. Is anybody out there who could hint me to the problem or give me a solution? Thanks guys, I really appreciate it!

Greetings
j0h4nn3s

Comment: well the request is obviously timing out. Check your network and ping the endpoint on the device using some other program to check if its reachable at all.

Comment: @FruitAddict how does it timeout if I don't get an error from the NSURLSession. I thought it would work like that: if I set a timeout in the config of the session, after that timeout, the didFinishWithError method will be called no mattered what happened before. Isn't it like that?
I can download the file from example the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some research, I found the problem and thought, I will post an answer in case anybody has the same problem.

Take a look at this function in the code:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    self.startTime = NSDate()
    self.endTime = self.startTime
}
```

A look in the corresponding [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:) gives the solution.
You have to call the completion handler like this to continue the transfer:

```
completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using blocks instead ?

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
//log here to see if it gets called, and test for error
}

task?.resume()
```

Comment: I want to use the delegate to measure the time precisely