# How to detect Network Signal Strength is weak in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can you help me how to detect Network Signal Strength is weak or strong  in iOS

1. Weak Network
2. Strong Network

Comment: its week or weak

Comment: Yes i knw question duplicate but i want answer  @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532651/how-to-detect-network-signal-strength-in-ios-reachability

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following library - https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit