# How to measure ios nsurlsession dowload task Speed?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

How to measure a downloadTask Speed:

The Method which I thought is:

calc the last 3s avg speed, and reset received Bytes after 3s, and start a NSTimer which every 0.8s call once.

But this will cause a problem: After 3s the NSTimer call at once, the received Bytes has been reset to 0, but I want a Smooth speed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271502/best-way-to-measure-download-speed-on-iphone-using-cocoa-touch

Comment: do you want something like a bar to show how much download is done?

Answer (score 0):

First, use NSURLSessionDelegate. If you are using completionHandler: delegate methods won't be called. Then in:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

you can add your own counter of `[data length]`. Collect and reset it in a synchronized way using NSTimer and you have it. Remember that NSTimer is not firing exactly as specified so if you need better precision store exact times of measurements